# Saving multiple Pandas data frames to different work sheets of a Single Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yF
import datetime
from functools import reduce


def get_returns_change_period(tic,com,OHLC_COL1,OHLC_COL2):
    df_Stock = yF.download(tickers = tic, period = "38y", interval = "1mo", prepost = False, repair = False)
    df_Stock['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Stock.index)
    df_Stock = df_Stock.sort_values(by='MONTH')
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(2) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(1) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(0) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
          
    return df_Stock.filter(regex='% Change')
```

Function defined and called.

```
get_returns_change_period('XOM','EXXON MOBIL','High','Open')
```

df_Industry contains 2 different companies and corresponding ticker symbols.

```
df_Industry = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1', '2'], 'Ticker': ['AIN', 'TILE'], 'Company':['Albany International', 'Interface']})


df1 = df_Industry.apply(lambda x: get_returns_change_period(x.Ticker, x.Company, 'High','Open'), axis=1)
```

Using Apply Lambda function to pass Ticker and Company names of different companies from Data Frame as Parameters to the function.

```
merged_df = pd.concat(df1.tolist(), axis=1)
merged_df

#merged_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
#merged_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This gives a single pandas data frame with both company details.

How to store the results in a single Excel File in 2 separate spreadsheets named after company names from df_Industry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, a quick solution would be to iterate over `df1` (*which seems to be a Series that holds a single DataFrame per each row*) and then, make the spreadsheets with [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    for df, sn in zip(df1, df_Industry["Company"]):
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sn)
```